# How to keep my goddaughter's legs from falling asleep from shoulder rides

Tags: pre-schooler

My oldest goddaughter adores riding on my shoulders, as a younger girl she didn't want held any other way then on my shoulders and just being put on my shoulders was enough to fix anything bothering her.  It's been a special part of our relationship.

However, lately she is getting big enough that her weight is causing her legs to fall asleep when she gets a longer ride (ie the rare occasion her younger sister doesn't start insisting on turns too).  I've tried telling my goddaughter that she has ridden long enough and her legs will fall asleep soon and she should get off, but she doesn't want to stop.  Specifically she insists they won't fall asleep.

Is there any tricks I can do to allow her longer rides without her having to deal with the pain of her legs falling asleep afterwards?

Comment: At the risk of sounding impertinent, how bony are your shoulders would you say?

Comment: I'm not really sure I have much of a frame of reference to say.  I'm somewhat on the skinny side so probably a little bonier then average?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short of having a saddle made for your shoulders, there's not much you can do to prevent the inevitable, so common sense is in order.

I don't know how old your oldest goddaughter is, how much she weighs, or how strong you are, but to prevent her legs from falling asleep, they need a short period of unrestricted blood flow.

If you are very strong or she is very light, you can lift her up off your shoulders by holding onto the sides of her chest wall (or, gently, her underarms if she's a lightweight) for 15-30 seconds every once in a while (well before her legs usually fall asleep.) You can tell her it's to give her a better vantage point (which it true!), or it's to rest your neck or shoulders, but this will prolong the time she can spend on her favorite perch.

Or you can take a short break where she walks or stands on her own - again, well before her legs usually fall asleep.

Maybe less intrusive than making her disembark is to shift to holding her against your chest for a few minutes. Although this also restricts blood flow some, it's a change that might help.

Finally, if you're arms are long and strong enough, and being an acrobat is in her future, you can have her *stand* on your shoulders for a minute while you hold her arms or upper chest securely. If she's small and light and you have long arms, it's doable and a fun challenge (better for you if she's in stocking feet or barefoot.) You can practice this trick at home while you're sitting on the floor with your back to the couch so if she falls, it's not far or likely to hurt her.

I think it's really nice that you are looking for ways to continue to share this activity with your goddaughter. I'm sure it's a very bonding kind of activity, one that she's 'bound' to fondly remember.

Comment: I could see her being an acrobat, though personally I always figured she would be in the rodeo.  She loved having me bouncer her around on my shoulders like I was a bull trying to buck her off, and was pretty good at hanging on ;)  Thank you for your answers.